# Objective-C No getter method error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm very new to Objective-C (and programming in general... I've only studied Python and a little bit of HTML). I am trying to learn from the tutorial **[here](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/learn-objectivec-objects-part-3-extending-the-fraction-class/62)** but I'm running into an error that I can't seem to get figured out.

In Fraction.m, under - (void)add:(Fraction *)newFraction I'm getting the error "No getter method for read from property" on the next two lines.

If anyone could help me out that would be great! Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

CODE:

FractionDemo.m

```
#import "Fraction.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {

    Fraction *aFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    Fraction *bFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];

    [aFraction setNumerator:1 overDenominator:2];
    [bFraction setNumerator:1 overDenominator:3];

    [aFraction display]; NSLog(@" + "); [bFraction display]; NSLog(@" = ");
    [aFraction add:bFraction];
    [aFraction display];

}
return 0;
}
```

Fraction.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject {
NSInteger numerator;
NSInteger denominator;
}
- (void)setNumerator:(NSInteger)value;
- (void)setDenominator:(NSInteger)value;
- (void)display;
- (void)setNumerator:(NSInteger)num overDenominator:(NSInteger)denom;
- (void)add:(Fraction *)newFraction;

@end
```

Fraction.m

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction
- (void)setNumerator:(NSInteger)value {
numerator = value;
}

- (void)setDenominator:(NSInteger)value {
denominator = value;
}

- (void)display {
NSString *numeratorString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)numerator];
NSString *denominatorString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)denominator];
NSLog(@"%@/%@", numeratorString, denominatorString);
}

- (void)setNumerator:(NSInteger)num overDenominator:(NSInteger)denom {
self.numerator = num;
self.denominator = denom;
}

- (void)add:(Fraction *)newFraction {
// a/b + c/d = ((a * d) + (b * c)) / (b * d)
self.numerator = self.numerator * newFraction.denominator + self.denominator * newFraction.numerator;
self.denominator = self.denominator * newFraction.denominator;
}

@end
```

Comment: Would suggest if u know python go for swift easy to learn

Comment: Can you try declaring numerator and denominator as properties??
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger numerator, denominator;

Comment: The tutorial is 5 years old. That's an era in terms of software life cycles. Look for a modern tutorial using real properties providing implicit setters and getters.

Comment: Try removing self from those two statements

Comment: Midhun, that didn't seem to work... thank you though!

Comment: If you don't use @properties you need to synthesize them yourself.

Comment: @Arun, I added that to my @ interface, and now my @ implementation gives this error for numerator and denominator: "Autosynthesized property 'denominator' will use synthesized instance variable '_denominator', not existing instance variable 'denominator'. The program will run, but outputs "1/2 + 1/3 = 0/0" rather than "1/2 + 1/3 = 5/6".

Comment: Change all numerator and denominator in your @implementation to self.numerator and self.denominator

Comment: OR you can can simply remove setNumerator and setDenominator methods from your @implementation

Comment: @Arun changed everything to self.numerator and self.denominator and removed the setNumerator and setDenominator methods -- the error is still there, but the program runs and outputs the correct fraction! This is good, but any idea why the error still exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions

**Solution 1**

Change all `self.numerator` to `numerator` and all `self.denominator` to `denominator`

**Solution 2**

Declare `numerator` and `denominator` as properties

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger numerator, denominator;
```

Now change all `numerator` to `self.numerator` and all `denominator` to `self.denominator`

***What I suggest is solution 2***

**Explanation**

Reason why you were getting the error was, in your original code numerator and denominator were class variables. So you can access them with the same name without using `self.`.The error was thrown on line where you used self.numerator.

One negative point of solution 1 is that you need to add your own setter and getter methods for those variables. But in solution 2, by declaring them as properties, OS will only create setter and getter methods. Only thing you need to do is access the variables using `self.`.

After declaring them as properties normal `numerator` wont work. You need to use `self.numerator`. This is the reason why you were getting error again. As I already said, if you are declaring them as properties, you don't need to add getter and setter methods as OS itself is creating them. So you can simply remove `setNumerator` and `setDenominator` methods

Comment: Thank you so much!